# Debugging my target application while running RestSharp?

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm running some tests with RestSharp that target an application in the same solution.  When I hit API methods with the RestSharp client, I'd like to be able to step through those methods, but it looks like I can only debug in the context of my test class and not within my api methods.

In other words - I'd like to hit GET /api/object/id with the RestSharp client and step through my objectController's GET method.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it in 2 stages instead:

1. debug the controller response (using e.g. fiddler to construct the request). This would be to make sure that this part of the system works as expected.
2. If you're happy with the response format then debug what you get from RestSharp through the test - at this stage you'd assume that the underlying response is correct and whatever dodgy responses you get has to be RestSharp issue. In this case you'd check the request format comparing with the original one you used in #1 to ensure that they are the same, check serialization etc.

Another way of doing it could be running your tests against a deployed version of the app - then you could attach to the proces and run the test. I think in this case you should be able to hit the breakpoints in controllers.

Is there any specific case that you have in mind?